# Query where @var Matches or @var is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am having a rather larger query inside a SP that can return quite a few results based on the variables. 1 segment should either return specific values if a var has a value or everything if the var has no value.

Basically i am attempting this:

```
@var = 'Not Empty'

Select * from Table
where ( 
        ( 
          x = @var 
          and ...(extra stuff)
        ) 
        or @var = ''
      )
      and y = ... (lots of extra stuff)
```

How ever this takes ages to load.
If i remove the OR it runs instant. 
I can't figure out why sql server has such a hard time with figuring out what to do. 
I could simply make two query's and put them inside an if but i rather not since the rest of the query is rather large and I would need to changes twice.

Does anyone have a clue what is going onunder the hood that makes this slow?

Comment: You can quickly see what is going on under the hood by looking at the execution plan and finding the expensive operator that occurs when you include your OR statement. That should give you some insight into what is happening (different join operator, seek vs scan, etc.). Also, '' <> NULL in SQL Server.

Comment: It's a shame SQL doesn't have 'or-else' or 'and-also' to help signify which conditions are expensive and which are quick.

Comment: Your title says `@var is null`, but the query shows `@var = ''`

Comment: `@var = ''` and `@var IS NULL` are not the same. Your title implies you are looking for `NULL` not a zero length string; which is it? If you're attempting to do different `WHERE` logic based on a parameter, you will probably find better performance from dynamic SQL. Then only the relevant parts of the `WHERE` need to be calculated, not all of them (and then excluded).

Comment: This is a type of catch-all query. There are some real challenges from a performance perspective for these things. Here is a great article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/

Comment: Can you try running the procedure with `with recompile`? Like `exec your_procedure @your_param = value with recompile`? If it runs faster, the problem is in parameter sniffing

Comment: @SeanLange , Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, You are correct I made a mistake in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try `union all`:

```
with t as (
      select t.*
      from table t
      where y = ... (lots of extra stuff) 
    )
Select t.*
from Table t
where @var is null 
union all
select t.*
from Table t
where @var = x and ...(extra stuff);
```

SQL Server can optimize each subquery separately.